# how fix this collapsable bootstrap sidebar menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

this code below works fine if I have 1 collapsable sidemenu item, but when I add another the upper item doesn't work right. It's all badly highlighted.
The bottom one works still fine. What's wrong here thanks.  Here is bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/IABXgPMp5S

```
<div class="container body-content">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub1">Sector One </a>
                        <ul class="nav  collapse pull-right" id="sub1">
                            <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub2">Sector Two</a>
                        <ul class="nav  collapse pull-right" id="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.row-->
  </div><!--/.container-->
```

and css file:

```
body {
  padding-top: 51px;  
}
.text-center {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#sidebar .nav {
  width: 95%;
}
#sidebar li {
  border:0 #f2f2f2 solid;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
}


/* collapsed sidebar styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-right
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -41.6%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -41.6%;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-right.active {
    right: 41.6%;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 41.6%;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 41.6%;
  }
  #sidebar {
    padding-top:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: please add bootply or jsfiddle

Comment: here it is:  http://www.bootply.com/IABXgPMp5S             Sector Two works fine, Sector One not. Unless I remove Sector Two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing the first "ul" before starting the second one, so bootstrap thinks you have one big unordered list.
[here](http://www.bootply.com/BiZJh0u3X5) is a link to the fix and here:

```
<div class="container body-content">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub1">Sector One <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down pull-right"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav  collapse pull-right" id="sub1">
                            <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub2">Sector Two <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down pull-right"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav  collapse pull-right" id="sub2">
                            <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.row-->
  </div><!--/.container-->
```

is the corrected html

Comment: gush, how come I didn't see this :( in Visual Studio nothing was shown as bad format. thanks! lost few hours on this :)

Comment: You are quite welcome. The original was valid (just not what you wanted) so your IDE wouldn't alert you to a mistake. If you suspect this issue in the future and are using VS you can put the cursor just after the starting brace or bracket and use ctrl + j to jump to the corresponding end bracket or brace -  [relevant link](https://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2008/07/09/jump-between-braces-in-visual-studio/)